# using ´this´ inside axios

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, nuxt.js

how can i use **this** inside axios?

example:

Don't work

```
this.$axios.get("").then(function(response){ this.data = response.data })
```

Works

```
let handler = this
this.$axios.get("").then(function(response){ handler.data = response.data })
```

is it possible to use the first option?

Comment: "is it possible to use the first option?" — No.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can, using an arrow function:

```
axios.get("").then(res => this.stuff = res.data)
```

This is because unlike regular anonymous functions, arrow functions don't have a `this` context and use the lexical scope's one

Comment: OP should use `async/await` syntax anyway.